# Tensorflow transform tensor with vector lookups

Tags: python, vector, tensorflow, lookup

Given a fixed dictionary with unique keys and values (all numbers are non-negative integers):

```
d = {(1,3): 6, (5,4): 9}
```

what would be an efficient way in tensorflow to transform:

```
tf.constant([[1,3], [5,4], [1,3]]) -> tf.constant([6, 9, 6])
```

and vice versa:

```
tf.constant([6, 9, 6]) -> tf.constant([[1,3], [5,4], [1,3]])
```

Answer (score 2):

As @OphirYoktan mentions, there's a lookup operator. I would recommend using  [`tf.embedding_lookup`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/embedding_lookup) but since you are aiming to also map `vector - id` you could do the following.

Use [`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn)

```
d_inverse = {v:k for k,v in d.items()}
d_mapped = tf.map_fn(lambda x: d[x], d.values())
d_mapped_inverse = tf.map_fn(lambda x: d_inverse[x], d_inverse.items()}
```

You only need to set the values in the dicts `d` and `d_inverse` as `tf.constants`

Having said that, these mappings should have to do with computational reasons regarding your graph, otherwise I would advice you to do them outside the graph.

Comment: map_fn should act on tensor not on values or items

Answer (score 1):

there's a lookuptable module in tensorflow - the documentation is at:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup

Comment: In order to use `lookup` you need to have a tensor and id's of the axis to lookup, so the second part : `tf.constant([6, 9, 6]) -> tf.constant([[1,3], [5,4], [1,3]])` could work if you have the right format. But the vector to id mapping would need more work.